# How can I show a custom model derived from QAbstractListModel in QListView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Custom data model that I will supply below based on QAbstractListModel will be in two views: a QWidget based control interface and QML based 'dashboard'. QWidget based control side must display model items (model rows) in a custom delegate with every data point with stated custom roles in model described below and also at least provide a button for calling an editor widget for changing data points provided by roles (i.e. date or starting hour for specific items).

```
class ScheduleModel(QAbstractListModel):

    SfiRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    NameRole = Qt.UserRole + 2
    ClsRole = Qt.UserRole + 3
    FlagRole = Qt.UserRole + 4
    OwnrRole = Qt.UserRole + 5
    RecordRole = Qt.UserRole + 6
    DeptRole = Qt.UserRole + 7
    DateStrRole = Qt.UserRole + 8
    HourRole = Qt.UserRole + 9
    EstTimeRole = Qt.UserRole + 10
    StatusRole = Qt.UserRole + 11

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._data = []

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data)

    @Slot()
    def updateSchedule(self, schedule_items: list):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._data = schedule_items
        self.endResetModel()

    def data(self, index=QModelIndex(), role: int = Qt.DisplayRole):
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() and index.isValid():
            item = self._data[index.row()]

            if role == self.SfiRole:
                return item.sfi
            elif role == self.NameRole:
                return item.item_name
            elif role == self.ClsRole:
                return item.class_attendance
            elif role == self.FlagRole:
                return item.flag_attendance
            elif role == self.OwnrRole:
                return item.owner_attendance
            elif role == self.RecordRole:
                return item.record_status
            elif role == self.DeptRole:
                return item.responsible_dept
            elif role == self.DateStrRole:
                return item.date
            elif role == self.HourRole:
                return item.start_hour
            elif role == self.EstTimeRole:
                return item.est
            elif role == self.StatusRole:
                return "Passive"

        else:
            return None

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = dict()

        roles[self.SfiRole] = b'sfiRole'
        roles[self.NameRole] = b'nameRole'
        roles[self.ClsRole] = b'clsRole'
        roles[self.FlagRole] = b'flagRole'
        roles[self.OwnrRole] = b'ownrRole'
        roles[self.RecordRole] = b'recordRole'
        roles[self.DeptRole] = b'deptRole'
        roles[self.DateStrRole] = b'dateStrRole'
        roles[self.HourRole] = b'hourRole'
        roles[self.EstTimeRole] = b'estTimeRole'
        roles[self.StatusRole] = b'statusRole'

        return roles
```

Model described above works for retaining data and calling by index and role names. I opt to use QListView and QStyledItemDelegate for displaying data in Qt based view. As far as i now, I must develop a paint method for display purposes and for basic models Qt uses DisplayRole for reading strings from data models. But as you can see from the model, I have not facilitated the DispplayRole and I have several custom roles for data points to display for each item in model. [image]
I try to create a paint method for a delegate that inherits from QStyledItemDelegate to paint something similar to this. I marked the roles on the picture for example.
In short the question is: Is it possible to override paint method of QStyledItemDelegate for displaying strings supplied by custom data roles and also display is it possible to draw buttons for calling editor widget within a custom delegate?

Comment: A Qt widget based item view by default displays data based on the roles: the `DisplayRole` returns a printable value (string or number), the `BackgroundRole` and `ForegroundRole` are used for tje background and text color of the item, respectively, etc. Each entry should only have *one* field and returns data about that field alone, but seeing your custom role names it seems that your data model has *many* fields for each entry, so you should probably opt for a *table* model instead.

Comment: I considered that for a very short period also. But it didn't feel right to do so because the "schedule" i work with also comes as an Excel spreadsheet. Thus i want to present data in a more "rounded up" manner on the QWidget based control side. For that reason I search for a "by the book" method of using custom roles in QListView. I hope I could explain myself. I'm still relatively new in UI programming.

Comment: If what you mean is that you want to alter the way entries are shown to the user, that's not an issue: delegates are also used exactly for that reason. If you clarify what the list view should display, we might better understand what you're trying to do and then give you more appropriate answers.

Comment: Edited my question for clarifying the issue a bit more. @musicamante thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @PerturbedMachinist your question is unclear

Comment: @eyllanesc rephrased the question. Hope this edit can clarify my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a QWidget based solution and I failed. After that Try to create and paint method to achieve look that i wanted. I am leaving my delegate class and paint method below as an example of a complex delegate.

```py
class TestItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    """A delegate to show test items in listview in qt side"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.model = self.parent().model()

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter,
              option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QModelIndex):

        model_ind = index.model()
        canvas = option.rect.getRect()

        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, on=True)

        # Supplying data from model
        sfi = index.data(model_ind.SfiRole)
        name = index.data(model_ind.NameRole)
        cls_att = index.data(model_ind.ClsRole)
        flg_att = index.data(model_ind.FlagRole)
        ownr_att = index.data(model_ind.OwnrRole)
        # rec_stat = index.data(model_ind.RecordRole)
        resp_dept = index.data(model_ind.DeptRole)
        date_str = index.data(model_ind.DateStrRole)
        hour_str = index.data(model_ind.HourRole)
        est_duration = index.data(model_ind.EstTimeRole)
        # status = model_ind.data(index, model_ind.StatusRole)

        # Frame and Background(s)
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor("Black")
        pen.setWidth(2)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(option.rect, 10, 10)

        painter.setPen(Qt.blue)
        # Coordinates for delegate background
        x, y, w, h = canvas

        # Drawing of the texts
        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x + 50, y, w-200, h//2),
            Qt.AlignVCenter, name)

        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x, y, h, h),
            Qt.AlignCenter, sfi)

        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x+w-150, y, 50, h//3),
            Qt.AlignVCenter,
            "C:{}".format('-' if cls_att == '' else cls_att))

        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x+w-150, y+h//3, 50, h//3),
            Qt.AlignVCenter,
            "F:{}".format('-' if flg_att == '' else flg_att))

        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x+w-150, y + 2*h//3, 50, h//3),
            Qt.AlignVCenter,
            "O:{}".format('-' if ownr_att == '' else ownr_att))

        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x+50, y+h//2, w//3, h//2),
            Qt.AlignVCenter, resp_dept)

        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x+w-100, y, 100, h//2),
            Qt.AlignCenter, date_str.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        )

        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x+w-100, y+h//2, 50, h//2),
            Qt.AlignCenter, hour_str.strftime('%H:%M')
        )

        painter.drawText(
            QRect(x+w-50, y+h//2, 50, h//2),
            Qt.AlignCenter, est_duration
        )

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        print(type(parent))

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        size = QSize(300, 50)
        return size
```

I set the model as selectable and editable via flags method of the model.

```py
def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return (Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable)

        return super().flags(index)
```

I am creating editor widget and relative methods right now. Might update this answer to leave a comprehensive answer after I achieved a feasible solution.